# Refresh referenced lists in ng-admin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, ng-admin

I'm using ng-admin with a rest API,
I have multiple referenced lists which are update frequently in the server side.

Is there a way to refresh referenced lists every 5 seconds or so using ng-admin?

EDIT: I already know about setInterval and $interval.
But I can't figure out where in ng-admin I should put it, what file exactly, that's where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Angular `$interval` service. This is just a wrapper around the native interval javascript function.

```
$interval(function() {
    // fetch results
}, 5000);
```

This function will run every 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds).

More information about `$interval` can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).